# How do I set it up so when my child uses iMessage I can see the messages?

Tags: ios, messages, apple-id, parental-controls

My daughter has an iPod and I have an iPad.  We both have separate Apple IDs.  How can I see her text message history on my iPad along with my own message history? If I change the Apple ID on my iPad between my ID and my child's, will the iMessage history show up each time I switch IDs on my iPad?

Answer (score 2):

On your iPad, go to `Settings > Messages > Send and Receive > Add Another Email` and enter her email address. This will generate a confirmation email to your daughter's address, if her email hasn't been used with this Apple ID before. She needs to click the link in that email for you to see her messages.

Comment: Can you expand this further - I have no settings->iMessage just Settings-Message and no text anything like " and add a her email for receiving iMessage"

Comment: @Mark Sorry for the confusion. I updated the answer to reflect the correct location of the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-messages-send and recieve from, and set it to your number and her #. you will get her messages and yours. on her iphone, do the same, but only set it to her #. hope i help!

Comment: Did you verify whether this works or is it just an assumption?